# Woocommerce Empty cart functions not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have a Wordpress - Woocommerce Website.On my website i added empty cart button by using following code.

```
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( isset( $_GET['empty-cart'] ) ) {
        echo "test";
        //exit;
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(true);
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_actions', 'patricks_add_clear_cart_button', 20 );
function patricks_add_clear_cart_button() {
    echo "<a class='button' href='?empty-cart=true'>" . __( 'Empty Cart', 'woocommerce' ) . "</a>";
}
```

This code is not working when user logged in.When user logged in apply the empty cart button then cart is not empty.This code only working at the time of user logged out.I am using latest version of woocommerce 3.2.2.

I can't understand how to fix.

Comment: Switch off all your plugins apart from WooCommerce and check if there are any plugin issues.  I tested the code you have copied and pasted from here and it works fine.  https://gist.github.com/BFTrick/4e94862ec64d56164b960aa16701e090

Comment: My problem is When user logged in apply the empty cart button then cart is not empty.Else its working.

Comment: This code works regardless of the user's login state.  If it doesn't empty the cart then you have a problem somewhere else.

Comment: Yes you are correct when i deactivating the Follow Up emails plugin then its working empty cart even user loggedin.

Comment: Send an email to the support team for that plugin and ask them if it's a known issue.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue while doing a front-end login via ajax which populates the cart and these solutions didn't work. The following worked for my case.

```
wp_set_current_user( $user_id); // Let woo commerce see the new user
WC()->cart->get_cart_from_session(); // Load users session
WC()->cart->empty_cart(true); // Empty the cart
WC()->session->set('cart', array()); // Empty the session cart data

// Blah Blah Blah ...

// WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);

// Blah Blah Blah ...

do_action('shutdown'); // Make woocommerce save the cart
die();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wc_load_cart()
```

Use this code use to refresh cart

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear also the user's session since the cart is stored there too.

```
// Empty cart
WC()->cart->empty_cart(true);
WC()->session->set('cart', array());
```

Comment: He's copy and pasted the code from here.  https://gist.github.com/BFTrick/4e94862ec64d56164b960aa16701e090  I tried the code and it works fine without clearing any sessions.  The empty_cart() function will clear persistent data by default.